# Replace codes with values in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with codes and their respective values, like:

```
cod <- data.frame("Sy" = c("11","12","13","14","15"),
                  "Class" = c("A","B","C","D","E"))
```

And other data.frame, where I need to replace the code with the value indicated previously. Some example:

```
dados <- data.frame("Sy" = c("14","13","14","11","14","14","12","15","13","14"),
                "Value" = c(""))
```

In short, I want to replace `"14"` in `dados` with `"D"`, `"13"` with `"C"`, and so on, getting:

```
"Sy"    "Value"
"14"    "D"
"13"    "C"
"14"    "D"
"11"    "A"
"14"    "D"
"14"    "D"
"12"    "B"
"15"    "E"
"13"    "C"
"14"    "D"
```

I know I could use:

```
for (i in c("11","12","13","14","15")) {
  dados$Value[which(dados$Sy == i)] <-cod$Class[which(cod$Sy == i)] 
}
```

But I need to use a larger `cod` data.frame, with hundreds of codes. Is there a handier way?

I would thank any help.

Comment: dados$Value <- cod$Class[match(dados$Sy, cod$Sy)]

Answer (score 1):

Just merge on your letter values:

```
dados <- merge(dados, cod, by="Sy", all.x=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- left_join(dados, cod, by = "Sy")
```

Answer (score 0):

By using plyr package:

```
  library(plyr)
  dados <- plyr::join(dados,
                      cod,
                      by = "Sy",
                      type = "left",
                      match = "all")
```